# How to retrieve the latest categories assigned to a post currently under editing?

Tags: wordpress, categories, publish

I need to limit the post tile length of a post belonging to a specific category while editing. So I need to check what categories have been assigned to the post under editing and decide whether to limit or not its post title.

I use "wp_insert_post_data" to do the job

`add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'limit_title_length' , '99', 2 );`

But what I found is that the categories returned from passed `$postarr` are existing categories. Not the latest categories. So it would not work for new post or if categories being changed while editing.

`$post_category = $postarr['post_category'];`

I also checked `get_the_category()` inside the function, and that also returns existing categories, not the latest categories if category assignment changed.

My codes so far...

```
function limit_title_length( $data,  $postarr ) {
// set up variables like max length, category id to limit
...

// get post id, title and categories from $data and $postarr passed
    $title =  $data['post_title'];
    $id = $postarr['ID'];
    $post_category = $postarr['post_category'];

// check if the specified category exists in the categories assigned to this post
...

// process $title, reset $post_title in $data 
...
    $data['post_title'] =  $title;
    return $data;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'limit_title_length' , '99', 2 );
```

`wp_insert_post_data` fires in the very late stage of post publishing. I expected to get the latest categories from `$postarr['post_category'];`
but it's not in my case here. Any solutions or alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

So just to be clear - You want to identify the most recent category added to a post?

If this is the case you will be hard pressed to do so as Wordpress does not save meta for added categories. If you are skilled enough you could script such a function and save the data in a custom table. Then retrieve it for use.

If you know the name of the category you are looking for you can use [has_category](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_category/)! .

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I understand it's a hard-pressed feature in WordPress. That's why I am hoping if anyone here can point to the direction or offer some hints on how to construct such a function you mentioned.

Comment: Good luck in your search, hopefully one of the seniors can offer some direction.